# Problem with Ajax Control Toolscript

Tags: web-config, ajax-control-tookit

Yesterday I tried to add the Ajax Control Toolkit to my solution, i first had some problems because I used the version for .NET 4.0, so i replace it and used the version made for .NET 3.5.

I only added this lines :

To add a calendar control to my page. The problem is that now i have a server error 
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error

And I don't get it to show the stack, i tried modifying the web.config, but it seems that the changes are not changing anything.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks

EDIT : Even if i take the line i added back i have the same issue, i deleted the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll of the references, retracted the solution and redeployed it, and i still have the same problem ...

EDIT2 : I just saw where the problem is the tag 
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
It seems that the assembly is not loading in the GAC ... I can't find it in the assembly folder

Comment: Have you added it as an additional assembly in your solution?

Comment: Well the assembly is in the Reference folder of my solution yes

Comment: That's not enough see answer

Answer (score 1):

In your VS2010 solution double click Package.package

In the bottom of the editor switch to the Advanced tab:
[image]

This will bring you to a screen where you can add external assemblies to the WSP package to inform SharePoint to put the assembly into GAC

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip, So the dll were added to the assembly folder, but i still have the problem. I tried to do a blank page, only with the reference to the dll :

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

And i got the same error. So should it be a problem coming from the assembly ?

Comment: Do you have any `<%@ Assembly Name="FULLNAME of ASSEMBLY"%>` before the `<%@ Register ...>`?

Comment: <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
That's the only two <%Assembly i have

Comment: Then the Assembly in your `<%@ Register>` should be with fullname so .net can load it from GAC

Comment: I just tried to put this : <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.51116, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %> but it didn't work